# Xamarin Monotouch Google Conversion Tracking to Track actual App Downloads

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, google-ads-api

Our SEO team has requested that I add Google Conversion tracking into our apps.

They sent me the below text.   Anyone with an idea of how to implement this via Monotouch ? I don't really follow what the snippet does,  so not sure how to re-write it ?  And the Google SDK is in Obj C ?

Any ideas ?

Below are the instructions on how to implement Conversion Tracking to Track actual App Downloads. The App Developer has to implement this.

> - Step 1: Download and import this SDK into your Xcode project http://dl.google.com/googleadmobadssdk/googleconversiontrackingsdkios.zip
> - Step 2: Make a call from the app that you'd like to track. Add the following code to your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.
>
> Learn more:
>   http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?answer=115794&hl=en_US.
>   // Google iOS Download tracking snippet
>   // To track downloads of your app, add this snippet to your
>   // application delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my initial Google searches came up with nothing, but some more research yielded the following code, which looks promising.

https://bitbucket.org/kirk/google-conversion-tracking-monotouch/commits/6f18a0a9555f93b868fa8f516df9c694